# What does this coordinate transformation in the Wave equation mean?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

My tutor derived the following of which I do not understand the transformations **(2.1)** and **(2.2)**:

$$\Delta\vec{E} - \frac{1}{c^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2}\vec{E}}{\partial t^{2}} = \frac{4\pi}{c^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} \vec{P}}{\partial t^{2}} \tag{1}$$

$$\tau = t - \frac{z}{c} \tag{2.1}$$
$$z' = z\tag{2.2}$$
$$(z,t) \longrightarrow (z',\tau)$$

He followed up with deriving the expressions for $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ in terms of $z'$ and $\tau$:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z'} \frac{\partial z'}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z'} - \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \tag{3.1}$$

$$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z^{2}} = \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z'^{2}} -\frac{2}{c}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z' \partial \tau} + \frac{1}{c^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \tau^{2}} \tag{3.2}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z'} \frac{\partial z'}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t} \tag{3.3} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}$$

Plugging this into **(1)** gives:
$$\frac{\partial^{2} \vec{E}}{\partial z'^{2}} - \frac{2}{c}\frac{\partial^{2} \vec{E}}{\partial z' \partial \tau} +
\require{cancel}
\cancel{\frac{1}{c^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2} \vec{E}}{\partial \tau^{2}}} -
\cancel{\frac{1}{c^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2} \vec{E}}{\partial \tau^{2}}} =
\frac{4\pi}{c^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} \vec{P}}{\partial \tau^{2}} \tag{4}$$

Obviously this alternate representation can be useful at times, but what does the initial transformation mean and why is it justified?

Comment: Why would you need to "justify" a transformation? $(z,t)$ are just coordinates, you're free to switch to others, e.g. your $(z,\tau)$. Also, this is known as [retarded time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_time).

Comment: Oh, wow! This is great! Thank you for the link! I learned much :D